# make unicode a string stored in a variable and then send it with telepot

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

**Introduction**

I'm creating a scraper bot with telepot and selenium and when i get the text data that i need to send with the telegram bot it is unreadabl, because it contains unicode-escape characters (emoji) in a wrong format like:

```
"hi I like this emoji: \\u265B\\u2655"
```

**Output**

```
"hi I like this emoji: \u265B\u2655"
```

**Needed Output**

```
"hi I like this emoji: ♕♛"
```

in my case i can't use `u"hi I like this emoji: \u265B\u2655"` because my string is stored in a variable obtained with selenium and regex

**What i have tried**

I used `json.loads("hi I like this emoji: \\u265B\\u2655")` i got this

**Exception Raised**

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**Question**

How can i format this string to obtain the needed output?

**Edit**

i tried yhis:

```
json.loads('"' + mystring + '"')
```

and i got:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 23 (char 22)
```

as asked in the comment this is the result of `print(repr(mystring))`:

```
'La Spezia\\ud83d\\udccd\\n\\ud83d\\udcdaLiceo Scientifico Sportivo A. Pacinotti\\ud83c\\udfeb\\nITALIAN FENCER \\ud83c\\uddee\\ud83c\\uddf9 \\ud83e\\udd3a SPCS!!\\nELECTRIC BASS\\ud83c\\udfb8\\ud83c\\udfb6\\nBooks \\ud83d\\udcd6\\n2a T ( ESCONI ) \\ud83d\\ude0d \\ud83c\\udf93'
```

Comment: You're *probably* simply looking at JSON encoding?! But that is rather unclear without more details.

Comment: I've edited the question being clearer about the problem and the situation, @deceze can you please vote to reopen it?

Comment: `json.loads('"hi I like this emoji: \\u265B\\u2655"')` → 'hi I like this emoji: ♛♕'…

Comment: There's a big difference between `json.loads('"..."')` and `json.loads("...")`. If you have a *JSON value* somewhere, that value should include double quotes. If you put that JSON value into a Python string literal, those quotes must be contained within the Python string literal, i.e.: `s = '"\\u265B..."'` to represent the JSON value `"\u265B..."`. *That* should be perfectly JSON-decodable. It's unclear what exactly you're dealing with and whether you're just failing because you copy a valid JSON value incorrectly into Python source code for testing, or something else…

Comment: To make this unambiguous, show `print(repr(the_json_string_you_extracted_from_somewhere))`.

Comment: You probably don't want to use regex to extract this string in the first place (there can did you handle escaped quotes?)

Comment: Works…?! https://repl.it/@DavidZentgraf/AccomplishedSqueakyLegacysystem

Comment: It isn't really clear what exactly can happen in the string. If it's just `\u<...>` you can easily do it with a regex, but what about escaped backslashes/other characters?

Comment: yes @deceze it works thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your final edit, the scraped string looks like a JSON-encoded string that was extracted directly out of a JSON file somewhere.  Strings in JSON need to be double-quoted to extract properly:

```
>>> import json
>>> s='La Spezia\\ud83d\\udccd\\n\\ud83d\\udcdaLiceo Scientifico Sportivo A. Pacinotti\\ud83c\\udfeb\\nITALIAN FENCER \\ud83c\\uddee\\ud83c\\uddf9 \\ud83e\\udd3a SPCS!!\\nELECTRIC BASS\\ud83c\\udfb8\\ud83c\\udfb6\\nBooks \\ud83d\\udcd6\\n2a T ( ESCONI ) \\ud83d\\ude0d \\ud83c\\udf93'
>>> print(json.loads(f'"{s}"'))
La Spezia
Liceo Scientifico Sportivo A. Pacinotti
ITALIAN FENCER   SPCS!!
ELECTRIC BASS
Books 
2a T ( ESCONI )
```